# How to use page cursor in GQL query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql

What is the correct way to use a datastore cursor in a GQL query? The following code works until I add the cursor:

```
$q = $db->gqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Post ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT @limit OFFSET @cursor', [
    'bindings' => [
        "limit" => 3,
        // Cursor retrieved using $posts[2]->cursor();
        "cursor" => 'CjgKEwoJdGltZXN0YW1wEgYIhPWOyQUSHWoIY2NhbGJsb2dyEQsSBFBvc3QYgICAgICAwAsMGAAgAQ=='
    ]
]);
$posts = $db->runQuery($q);
```

This results in the error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Binding site @cursor for offset bound to non-integer value parameter.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","code":400}}
```

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference) clearly state:

> OFFSET: Specifies offsets into the result set: either a cursor, or a
>   count, or both

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running the query from your google cloud console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query/gql

If you're able to execute it then there is likely something wrong with the php client library. In which case you may have to use Datastore's REST-based API and use curl to run the query.

If you weren't able to run the query from the console then it may be that you can't use cursors with certain types of queries (that ORDER BY looks like its might be problematic).

Comment: Alternatively you could try enabling literals (by setting the allowLiterals option to true) and adding the limit and cursor values directly to the query string. This can be dangerous though as it leaves your application open to scripting attacks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work using GQL from the console either...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Having the same problem.

Comment: Never found a solution, doesn't look like cursors are available using GQL